Is local dependency resolution possible in .NET without NuGet?
I have two class library .NET projects, B and C, which depend both on another class library project, D.
Both B and C have respective CLI wrapper projects which they need to build independently with, but together they also form a part of an app project, A, which then means that duplication of D occurs.
The typical advice I found for this setup is to make D into a NuGet package and refer to the package from all three A, B, and C.
I'm sure this is good advice in many scenarios, but I feel that it is a bit too complicated for my needs because:

I'm only using D in these projects.
I'm the only developer working on these four projects.
I think having a local setup would be simpler than setting up a private NuGet server or packages on my GitHub account.
I'd like to be able to make changes to D on the fly while working on either A, B, or C.

Is there a way to instead simply change the Include value of ProjectReference in both B and C, based on if they are built independently or under A, effectively achieving local dependency resolution without NuGet?

I assume you mean a "shared project". A .NET shared project doesn't produce an assembly and doesn't produce an equivalent of a C\C++ static library. When a shared project is referenced, the source files in the shared project are added to the referencing project. I assume B, C, and D are all shared projects. When A references B and C, the files from D have been added to B and C and A receives duplicate files. Is this the issue?

You don't need a "private NuGet server". A NuGet package source can be a directory.

If "local dependency resolution" means find a package by name in a package source then no, local dependency resolution is not possible in .NET without NuGet. But if the assumption is that NuGet doesn't provide local dependency resolution, that is incorrect. A local feed can be created which is just a directory. A NuGet server is not required.

Note that ProjectReference and PackageReference are just Item collections and the metadata can be set and/or modified dynamically in the evaluation phase.

Thanks and sorry for the confusion – B, C, and D are all class libraries (I've adjusted the question to the proper .NET lingo).

A local NuGet feed is interesting, but if I'm not mistaken, would require me to pre-pack D. I'm looking for a workflow where D's sources are compiled along with the referring projects so that changes to them would immediately apply when recompiling A, for example.

If projects B, C, and D are class library projects (class library projects produce .dll files), then there is no duplication issue. All four projects (A, B, C, and D) can be in one solution file (.sln).

I'm afraid it's a bit more complicated because I have 3 separate solutions in which these libraries are used. I was hoping for a way to pass data from A to both B and C on how to refer to D depending on the solution, but I think I will just resort to having D in the same relative path in each solution. Thanks!

You should modify your question to make it clear that D is used across multiple solutions. (I'm sure that it's because D is used across multiple solutions that the advice has been to make D a NuGet package.)

I figured it out. Using Directory.Build.props files, one can set global properties that apply to every project in the file's directory and below it.
This lets me change the Include location of any ProjectReference depending on the higher level repository that the reference is made under, which is exactly what I was looking for.
Here's the setup I ended up with.
In both the project files of B and C, I defined a default loacation for D, and changed its project references like so:
<PropertyGroup>
    <DLocation Condition="'$(DLocation)' == ''">..\Submodules\D\D\D.csproj</DLocation>
</PropertyGroup>
  
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="$(DLocation)" />
</ItemGroup>

When I build B or C by themselves (like with their independent CLI wrappers), they both take D from a location inside their repositories – just like before. But, when I check either of them out as submodules under A, I can tell them to take D from a central location belonging to A with the following Directory.Build.props file located in A:
<Project>
   <PropertyGroup>
      <DLocation>$(SolutionDir)Submodules\D\D\D.csproj</DLocation>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Now, when working on A, I know that all three A, B, and C are using the same copy of D (I can make this choice because I test all three together) and I can make in-place changes to D that apply to all and build right away.
